# How to add a line break before and after a regex in a text file?

Tags: regex, text, edit

This is an excerpt from the file I want to edit:

```
>chr1|-|9|S|somatic ACCACAGCCCTGTTTTACGTTGCGTCATCGCCCCGGGTGCCTGGTGACGTCACCAGCCCGCTCG >chr1|+|9|Y|somatic ACCACAGCCCTGTTTTACGTTGCGTCATCGCCCCGGGTGCCTGGTGACGTCACCAGCCCGCTCG
```

I would a new text file in which I add a line break before ">" and after "somatic" or after "germline", how can I do in R or Unix?

Expected output:

```
>chr1|-|9|S|somatic
ACCACAGCCCTGTTTTACGTTGCGTCATCGCCCCGGGTGCCTGGTGACGTCACCAGCCCGCTCG
>chr1|+|9|Y|somatic
ACCACAGCCCTGTTTTACGTTGCGTCATCGCCCCGGGTGCCTGGTGACGTCACCAGCCCGCTCG
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: You need to state 1. The tool/language you are using the regex in and 2. your attempt. Please keep that in mind next time you ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of your input, you could simply replace spaces with newlines:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' <infile >outfile
```

(Some `tr` dialects don't like `\n`.  Try `'\012'` or a literal newline: opening quote, newline, closing quote.)

If that won't work, you can easily do this in `sed`.  If `somatic` is static, just hard-code it:

```
sed -e 's/somatic */&\n/g' -e 's/ >/\n>/g' file >newfile
```

The usual caveats about different `sed` dialects apply.  Some versions don't like `\n` for newline, some want a newline or a semicolon instead of multiple `-e` arguments.

On Linux, you can modify the file in-place:

```
sed -i 's/somatic */&\
/g
s/ >/\
/g' file
```

(For variation, I'm showing how to do this if your `sed` doesn't recognize `\n` but allows literal newlines, and how to put the script in a single multi-line string.)

On *BSD (including MacOS) you need to add an argument to `-i` always; `sed -i '' ...`

If `somatic` is variable, but you always want to replace the first space after a wedge, try something like

```
sed 's/\(>[^ ]*\) /\1\n/g'
```

`>[^ ]` matches a wedge followed by zero or more non-space characters.  The parentheses capture the matched string into `\1`.  Again, some `sed` variants don't want backslashes in front of the parentheses, or are otherwise just ... different.

If you have very long lines, you might bump into a `sed` which has problems with that.  Maybe try Perl instead.  (Luckily, no dialects to worry about!)

```
perl -i -pe 's/(>[^ ]*) /$1\n/g;s/ >/\n>/g' file
```

(Skip the `-i` option if you don't want to modify the input file.  Then output will be to standard output.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I used your first suggestion and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

```
(\bsomatic\b|\bgermline\b)|(?=>)
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `$1\n`

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/53

If there's no support for lookahead then try

```
(\bsomatic\b|\bgermline\b)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1\n`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/50

and

```
(>)
```

Replace by `\n$1`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/51

Comment: Replacing `>` globally will inject an empty line before the first line.  You can add a lookbehind, or replace `(.)(>)` with `$1\n$2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone!
I used:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' <infile >outfile
```

as suggested by tripleee and it worked perfectly!